# Setoid Rewriting asking for trivial morphism?

Tags: coq

I'm getting the following error when I call `setoid_rewrite (kron_1_r U)` on the goal `U == U ⊗ I 1` (where `==` is `mat_equiv` and `⊗` is `kron`):

```
Ltac call to "setoid_rewrite (orient) (glob_constr_with_bindings)" failed.
setoid rewrite failed: Unable to satisfy the following constraints:
In environment:
W : WType
u : Unitary W
ρ : Square (2 ^ ⟦ W ⟧)
H : Mixed_State ρ
U : Square (2 ^ ⟦ W ⟧)
HeqU : U = denote_unitary u
do_subrelation := Morphisms.do_subrelation : Morphisms.apply_subrelation

?p : "Morphisms.Proper (mat_equiv ==> flip impl) (mat_equiv U)"
```

I tried proving that `Morphisms.Proper (mat_equiv ==> flip impl) (mat_equiv U)` and it's trivial - it follows from `mat_equiv` being an equivalence relation (which I've already declared).

Any idea what might be going on and how I can resolve it?

(Relevant declared morphisms are kron from `==` and `==` to `==`, and Mixed_State from `==` to `iff`. The latter isn't explicit here, but I used it earlier in the proof and ordinarily I can this rewriting.)

Comment: You need to ensure that the type class machinery can find the `Proper` instances for this rewrite to work. Did you declare your lemma as an instance? (A gist might help diagnose the problem, if it is not too complex...)

Comment: Which lemma? `Morphisms.Proper (mat_equiv ==> flip impl) (mat_equiv U)`? I just asserted it - it's not clear to me why Coq would need it. (Also, I'm not sure how to add this using `Add Parametric Morphism` or `Instance`. Morphisms.Proper isn't a record?)

Comment: Yes, that lemma. Do you mean that you asserted it the middle of the problematic proof? Having access to the code would really make a difference, I think.

Comment: Yeah, I did. 

It's the `denote_gate_correct` lemma here: https://github.com/inQWIRE/QWIRE/blob/mat_equiv/Denotation.v

Comment: @Rand00 I had a look at your gist and `kron_1_r` proves an equality using `Logic.eq`, not `mat_equiv`, thus a standard rewrite should work.

Comment: `kron_1_r` is defined here and it uses `mat_equiv`: https://github.com/inQWIRE/QWIRE/blob/mat_equiv/Matrix.v#L679

Comment: @Rand00 Indeed, I was looking at the main branch. After some investigation, your rewrite fails because `kron_1_r` contains `1 * m` and `1 * n` as implicit arguments. I don't know why the error message is incomprehensible, though.